# Microsoft exchange/outlook "tasks" in linux/evolution?

Tags: linux, exchange, outlook, evolution

Ive tried receiving Microsoft outlook/exchange tasks (like meetings and duties) with "evolution"(evolution) without any success...

Have anyone succeed with evolution or other linux program??
This is the only thing stopping me to say good by to microsft windows...

Best Regards and thanks for the great Site !!

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me.

Note: You need to use Evolutions Exchange Connector which connects to Exchange via OWA. I think newer versions of Evolution actually use MAPI though.

Comment: Last time I checked the MAPI connector didn't work very well. OWA works fine for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are talking about receiving outlook/exchange tasks from a server or are you talking about a reminder type of setup. I  use  KOrganizer to setup reminder, todo list. and journal entry.

Answer (score 0):

HI,

I am not finding evolution having the option to handle rpc over https by which outlook anywhere work.  I have tried this in ubuntu beta 10.01